# AMPL finds optimal solution zero, all variables are set to zero

Tags: binary, continuous, ampl

This is the first time I'm using AMPL and I am not really familiar with it. 
I have to optimize my model but I think my codes are wrong and I keep getting as the optimal solution and "NOS 5.51: ignoring integrality of 20 variables". 
My model is to 
Min (waste)
subject to 
[I attached a picture of constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Brfx.png)

and here are my codes :

```
`set DAY;     #the day we buy ingredient
 set INGRED;   #fresh ingredients
 set TIME;     #day that keeps track of the inventory
 param M default 0;
 param cost{INGRED} > 0; #cost for each ingredient (per pound)
 param demand{TIME, INGRED} >= 0; #the expected demand for each ingredient fo each day t
 param min_pur_req > 0;  #minimum total cost of order required to get a delivery
 param expiry{INGRED} ; #shelf life of each ingredient
 var amount{t in TIME, i in DAY, j in INGRED} >=0; #is defined only for t = i
 var is_bought {t in TIME,i in DAY,j in  INGRED : i <= t }binary; #only for t =i
 var inventory {t in TIME,i in DAY, j in INGRED : i<=t <= i+expiry[j] } >= 0; # t >= i
 var used{t in TIME,i in DAY, j in INGRED :  i <= t <= i+expiry[j]} >= 0; 
 var waste{t in TIME,i in DAY, j in INGRED : t <= i+expiry[j] } >= 0;`
 minimize Total_waste: 
        sum{t in TIME,i in DAY, j in INGRED : i <= t <= i+expiry[j]} waste[t,i,j];
subject to invalid_amount{t in TIME, i in DAY, j in INGRED: i <= t <= i+expiry[j]}: 
      if t != i then amount[t,i,j] = 0;
subject to invalid_binary{t in TIME, i in DAY, j in INGRED: i <= t <= i+expiry[j]}:
     if t != i then is_bought[t,i,j] = 0;
subject to usage{t in TIME, j in INGRED}:
    sum {i in DAY: i <= t <= i + expiry[j]} used[t,i,j] = demand[t, j];
subject to inventory_formula {t in TIME, i in DAY, j in INGRED: i+1 <= t <= i+expiry[j]}: 
    waste[t,i,j] = amount[t,i,j] + inventory[t-1,i,j] - used[t,i,j] - inventory[t,i,j] ;
subject to cost_check {t in TIME, i in DAY: t = i}:
    sum {j in INGRED} cost[j]*amount[t,i,j] >=  sum{j in INGRED: t <= i+expiry[j]} min_pur_req*is_bought[t,i,j];
subject to blah{t in TIME,i in DAY, j in INGRED: i <= t <= i+expiry[j]}:
        amount[t,i,j] <= M*is_bought[t,i,j];
subject to  invalid_inventory{t in TIME, i in DAY, j in INGRED: i+1 <= t <= i+expiry[j]}: 
 #i+1 because for i = 1 i get error in invetory[0,1,j] 
      if t=i then inventory[t-1,i,j] = 0;
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
ampl: model waste.mod;
ampl: data waste.dat;
ampl: solve;
MINOS 5.51: ignoring integrality of 20 variables
MINOS 5.51: optimal solution found.
23 iterations, objective 0
```

Answer (score 0):

MINOS solver doesn't support binary variables, only continuous. So it ignores (relaxes) integrality and warns about it with the message "ignoring integrality of 20 variables". You should use a mixed-integer programming [AMPL](http://ampl.com/) solver such as [CPLEX](http://ampl.com/products/solvers/solvers-we-sell/cplex/) or [Gurobi](http://ampl.com/products/solvers/solvers-we-sell/gurobi/) to get an integer solution.